# Material-UI 4.8.1 API change - new way to specify the `component` property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

**Edit**: This was a bug in the typing of 4.8.x, upgrade to 4.9.0+ to fix the issue.

---

On version `4.8.0`, the following code compiles and runs fine:

```
      <DialogContent>
        {/* use a span so we can nest div, p, etc. */}
        <DialogContentText component="span">
          {confirmContent}
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
```

After upgrading to `4.8.1` the code now fails type-checking with:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: DialogContentTextProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, a
ny, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogContentTextProps'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogContentTextProps'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<DialogContentTextProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any)
=> Component<...>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogContentTextProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogContentTextProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2769
```

I can get my project compiling again by deleting the `component="span"` part - but what's the proper fix?

What's the new way to specify way to specify the base component used by `DialogContentText`?

My project is a standard `create-react-app` setup, using `Typescript` `3.7.4`.

Comment: Exactly same issue here but using Drawer component and trying to make it use the "nav" component.

Comment: @Jamie Shepherd - are you able to provide an example of the problem with `Drawer`?  The `DialogContentText` problem has been acknowledged in a Github issue but they are unclear about how it would affect `Drawer` -

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19068#issuecomment-570774036

Comment: Some documentation implied the "component" prop was on all components when it is not - docs have been updated. This was my issue as draw does not have a "component" prop. The DialogContentText also does not implement the "component" prop, however you should be able to use it because any other props should be forwarded to the Typography component that does implement the component prop. My thoughts here is perhaps during an updated there was a mistake not taking into account that the type for DialogContentText should extend the Typography type? Perhaps worth digging into some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the typings in `material-ui`, see: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19068

Fixed in 4.9.0