# Typescript Routing Error - No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes

I am trying to redirect to a sign up page when a button is clicked, however, I am receiving a 'no overload matches this call error'. I tried to Google the error however it seems quite broad and I am new to Typescript so unsure how to fix it.

How should I fix the error and how should i display the sign up form when the button is clicked?

```
// Main.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, useRouteMatch, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import { SignUp } from "./SignUp";

function Main() {
    // some stuff above
    <Button component= { Link } to="/signup" variant="contained" color="primary">Sign up!</Button>
    // some stuff below
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/">
                <Main />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup">
                <SignUp />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>),document.getElementById("main")
);
```

This is the error message I am receiving:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean; href?: string; size?: "medium" | ... 1 more ... | "small"; startIcon?: ReactNode; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: OverridableComponent>; to: string; type: string; fullWidth: true; variant: "contained"; color: "primary"; className: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: OverridableComponent>; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: OverridableComponent>; to: string; type: "submit"; fullWidth: true; variant: "contained"; color: "primary"; className: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; endIcon?: ReactNode; ... 4 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; endIcon?: ReactNode; ... 4 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.

Comment: have you imported SignUp component?

Comment: yes I have, i forgot to include in code sample, let me edit

Answer (score 4):

This is an exeption of material-ui and it means that your component uses props that it's not supposed to have.

If you do this:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

<Button component={Link} to="/signup" variant="contained" color="primary">Sign up!</Button>
```

You say react, that you want to render a Button as a Material-Ui Link. The problem is, that the Material Ui Link https://material-ui.com/api/link/ does not have a "to" prop. therefore you get the exception.

If you use React Router, change your code like this:

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

<Button component={RouterLink} to="/singup" variant="contained" color="primary">Sign up!</Button>
```

If you do this, you tell React that you want to render your Button as a RouterLink from react-router-dom. This Link now does have a to prop like you're used to.

Alternatively you could use the "href" prop from the material-ui Link Component but that would mess up with your routing since this would render a normal `<a href=""></a>` instead of a React-Router `<Link>`.

Comment: Hi, I tried following your suggestion however the error is still there

Comment: @M.Ng did you try the example with component={RouterLink}?

Comment: Yes, I followed your example

Comment: @M.Ng try upgrading material-ui, this might be a bug in their typing because the above example works for my code (material-ui 4.9.13) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494907/material-ui-4-8-1-api-change-new-way-to-specify-the-component-property

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1", which material ui are you referring to?

Comment: @M.Ng @material-ui/core of course. You can check with your import statements (you import @material-ui/core/button, therefore you need to upgrade material-ui-core

Comment: I tried changing to 4.9.13 by changing the dependencies in the package.json file and then running npm install again however I am still getting the error. Would there be an alternative solution?

Comment: use npm update material-ui/core to ensure it's up to date and make sure to restart your app

Comment: It's still not working, i really don't understand why. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Maybe try to update your typescript package as well (npm update typescript) and npm update @types/material-ui

Answer (score -3):

Can you change your routing and try defining route like this i hope it will help

```
<Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
```